# Does Template pattern violate Single Responsibility principle?

Tags: single-responsibility, template-method

Assume we have the following class:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void func()
    {
    _func1();
    _func2();
    }
private:
    virtual void _func1();
    virtual void _func2();
};
```

This class, from one side, specifies the interface (`foo` method), and, from the other side, it defines the implementation (first we call `_func1`, then `_func2`). So does it violate the Single Responsibility principle?

Comment: It does one thing: provides `func()`. How it implements `func()`, in this case by spreading the functionality over `_func1()` and `_func2()` is an implementation detail unrelated to the SRP.

Comment: It violates not SOLID, it violates encapsulation :)

Answer (score 1):

No. Not per se.

If you rephrase *SRP* as »doing one thing only«, you would be right, but that is not, what *SRP* means.

You should read *SRP* more like: »dealing with one level of abstraction«

What »one level of abstraction« is, is left to the reader as an exercise.

Comment: That is the fun thing about principles: they say, "it should look like this" and then you have to interpret 'it', 'should', 'look like' and 'this'.

Comment: SPR says not to do 1 level of abstraction, but: you must have only one reason to change this logic. And that's it! Not equal not to do 1 thing not to 1 abstraction.

Comment: @ArtemA therefore I wrote "you should read" as an exegesis of what was intended. If you have one level of abstraction there is only one reason to change.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it does - to some degree. That's why there is another pattern to achieve effectively the same, but without violating the SRP: the *strategy* pattern, used in a "context class" like this:

```
class Context
{
private:
    IStrategy *_strategy;

public:
    void func()
    {
      _strategy->_func1();
      _strategy->_func2();
    }
};
```

However, as always when making design decisions, this is a trade-off: using the strategy pattern produces a little bit more boilerplate code, and the virtual functions now must be made `public` instead of `protected`, so it loosens encapsulation to some degree. You will have to trade "YAGNI" vs.  "SRP" here.

For small classes or template methods, the "template method pattern" is totally sufficient, for bigger ones, "strategy" may be the better choice. And sometimes, using no pattern at all is [the best solution of all](https://blog.codinghorror.com/head-first-design-patterns/).

Comment: That's the fun thing about design patterns: [there are so many of them.](https://xkcd.com/927/)